# C# New Row, BindingSource, DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, datasource, bindingsource

i have thress classes
1. class

```
    public class Episode
{
    public int Folge { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Vorhanden { get; set; }
    public Episode(int Folge, string Name, string Vorhanden)
    {
        this.Folge = Folge;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Vorhanden = Vorhanden;
    }
}
```

2. class

```
public class Staffeln
{
    public int Staffel { get; set; }
    public List<Episode> Episoden { get; set; }
    public Staffeln(int Staffel)
    {
        this.Staffel = Staffel;
    }
}
```

3. class

```
public class Serien
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Staffeln> Staffeln { get; set; }
    public Serien(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Then i have a Form with a combobox and a DataGridView.
The Combobox settings are:
DataSource: StaffelnBindingSource
DisplayMember: Staffel
ValueMember: Staffel

and DataGridview Settings are:
DataSource: episodenBindingSource

Staffel in english is Season and Episoden are Episodes. Its a List for me.
When i select season 9 in the combobox, then show the dgv the episodes.

Now, i want add more Episodes to the Season, but i dont know how. 
i try to add the Episodes to the list and set the bindingsource to the list again:

```
staffelnBindingSource.DataSource = Serien[SerienZahl].Staffeln;
```

i have also tried

```
dgvEpisoden.DataSource = episodenBindingSource;
```

but it dont works.
sorry for my english.

Comment: Use a BindingList instead of a List.  Make sure your lists are properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try clearing/refreshing the datagrid when you need to change the binding source.

```
dgvEpisoden.Rows.Clear();
dgvEpisoden.Refresh();
```